# What's wrong, I cannot create this table

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

That's my first time using Firebird. I am trying to create this table. I checked the docs and it seems ok. What's wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE ENDERECO 
(
      ID_ENDERECO INTEGER generated by default as identity primary KEY,
     RUA VARCHAR(50), 
     BAIRRO VARCHAR(35),
     CEP VARCHAR(10),
     COMPLEMENTO VARCHAR(35),
     ECOMERCIO INTEGER(1),
     ESTADO CHAR(2)

)
```

Comment: Did you check for any console error?

Comment: Error message that you got can provide you a hint. Integers in Firebird have no precision in syntax.

Comment: When asking a question about something that fails, please include the error (in this case `Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000, Dynamic SQL Error, -SQL error code = -104, -Token unknown - line 8, column 23, -(`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of `INTEGER(1)`. The data type `INTEGER` (and `SMALLINT` and `BIGINT`) do not have a precision in their definition. See also [Data Type Declaration Syntax](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-datatypes-syntax) in the Firebird 3 Language Reference:

```
<domain_or_non_array_type> ::=
    <scalar_datatype>
  | <blob_datatype>
  | [TYPE OF] domain
  | TYPE OF COLUMN rel.col

<scalar_datatype> ::=
    SMALLINT | INT[EGER] | BIGINT
  | FLOAT | DOUBLE PRECISION
  | BOOLEAN
  | DATE | TIME | TIMESTAMP
  | {DECIMAL | NUMERIC} [(precision [, scale])]
  | {VARCHAR | {CHAR | CHARACTER} VARYING} (length)
    [CHARACTER SET charset]
  | {CHAR | CHARACTER} [(length)] [CHARACTER SET charset]
  | {NCHAR | NATIONAL {CHARACTER | CHAR}} VARYING (length)
  | {NCHAR | NATIONAL {CHARACTER | CHAR}} [(length)]
```

In short, use:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ENDERECO 
(
     ID_ENDERECO INTEGER generated by default as identity primary KEY,
     RUA VARCHAR(50), 
     BAIRRO VARCHAR(35),
     CEP VARCHAR(10),
     COMPLEMENTO VARCHAR(35),
     ECOMERCIO INTEGER,
     ESTADO CHAR(2)
)
```